# How to split column and row in shopping cart with java JSP or JSF

Tags: jsp, jsf

i want to present one shopping cart in index
i want to show 3 column and 5 row for each category 
Example

```
Books
||  Books A   ||   Books B     || Books C
||============||===============||=========
||  Books D   ||    Books E    ||  Books F
||============||===============||=========
||  Books G   ||     Books H   ||  Books I

Video
||   Video A  || Video B       ||  Video C
||============||===============||=========
||  Video D   || Video E       || Video F
||============||===============||=========
|| Video G    || Video H       || Video I
```

How can i do it like my example ?

Comment: JSF 1.x or 2.x? If 2.x (as you told in a comment of one of your previous questions), why are you using JSP instead of Facelets? After all, answer really depends on JSF version (1.x or 2.x) and view technology (JSP or Facelets) used. You should be more explicit about that in future JSF questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use JSF2.0 and Facelets, you could use `<ui:repeat>` and `<h:dataTable>` tags. Make your bean return items grouped in categories. In categories, keep list of items rows. Row is just an array (could be list too).

```
@ManagedBean
public class Cart {
  List<CategoryItems> getItemsGroupedInCategories() {
    //get items here
  }
}

public class CategoryItems {
  private String categoryName;
  private List<Item[]> itemsRows;
  //constructors, getters/setters
}
```

Then in JSF XHTML you put:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{cart.itemsGroupedInCategories}" var="categoryItems">
  <h:dataTable value="#{categoryItems.itemsRows}" var="row" >
    <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="#{categoryItems.categoryName}" />
    </f:facet> 
    <h:column>
      <h:outputText value="#{row[0]}" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
      <h:outputText value="#{row[1]}" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
      <h:outputText value="#{row[2]}" />
    </h:column>
  </h:dataTable>
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: I disagree using `h:dataTable` here. But I can't answer until the OP clarifies the environmental details. I just don't want to post about 4 different ways to achieve this the right way depending on the environment.

Comment: Ok, but why do you disagree using `h:dataTable`?